# When trying to edit a configurable product … lost on this error… how to fix it

Tags: magento2

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/magento2/www/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php
>   on line 43

Magento 2.2.8